# Provided dependency failing to provide

Tags: scala, hadoop, gradle, dependency-management

I got a Scalding (a hadoop abstraction layer in Scala) project that I'm trying to build using Gradle.

Looks like Hadoop [became a *provided* dependency](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cascading-user/aauSI3UbHpw/-n118YBX2MkJ) in latest releases and it requires some workaround.

So I patched my build.gradle script like so:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'
configurations {
    provided
}
sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
}
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  maven{
    url 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
    }
}
ext.cascadingVersion = '2.1.6'
ext.hadoopVersion = '1.1.2'
dependencies {
  compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.2'
  compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.2'
  compile 'bixo:bixo-core:0.9.1'
  compile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.7'
  testCompile  'org.scala-tools.testing:specs:1.6.2.2_1.5.0'
  compile( 'com.twitter:scalding_2.9.2:0.8.1' )
  compile( group: 'cascading', name: 'cascading-core', version: cascadingVersion )
  compile( group: 'cascading', name: 'cascading-hadoop', version: cascadingVersion )
  provided "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:${hadoopVersion}"
}
jar {
  description = "Assembles a Hadoop-ready JAR file"
  doFirst {
    into( 'lib' ) {
      from configurations.compile
    }
  }
  manifest {
    attributes( "Main-Class": "com.Crawler" )
  }
}
```

Which I thought would solve the problem. But I keep getting the following error at when trying to build:

```
[ant:scalac] Element '/Users/tkmafj4/Projects/AIT/Crawler/build/resources/main' does not exist.
[ant:scalac] scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeError: class file needed by Source is missing.
[ant:scalac] reference value hadoop of package org.apache refers to nonexisting symbol.
```

Which looks a lot like there's something missing in my configuration.

How can I check that sources are being fetched?

What is the proper workaround to get this to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hadoop` becoming a "provided" dependency of `cascading` means that depending on `cascading` will no longer pull in `hadoop`, because `hadoop` is meant to be provided by the target environment or by whoever creates the ultimate deployable archive. If the `hadoop` dependency needs to go into your fat Jar, you need to make it (at least) a `runtime` dependency. But since there appears to be some problem with compilation, I'd try to make it a `compile` dependency.

If the `hadoop` dependency should go on the compile class path but not into the fat Jar, you'll need to add something like `sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided`.

PS: Your fat Jar task needs to package `configurations.runtime` rather than `configurations.compile`, and the `doFirst {` line (as well as the corresponding closing brace) should be removed.