# Gradle built jar does not find my main class

Tags: gradle, program-entry-point, scalding

At work we use gradle on a Scalding project and I'm trying to come up with the simplest job to get the hand out of the stack.

My class looks as :

```
package org.playground

import com.twitter.scalding._

class readCsv(args: Args) extends Job(args) {

    val csv:Csv = Csv(args("input"), ("firstName", "lastName"))
    println(csv)
}
```

and lives `in playground/src/org/playground/readCsv.scala`. My build script looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

archivesBaseName = 'playground'

mainClassName = 'org.playground.readCsv'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  maven{ 
        url 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
        artifactUrls  'http://clojars.org/repo/‎'
        artifactUrls  'http://maven.twttr.com/'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.2'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.2'
    compile 'bixo:bixo-core:0.9.1'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.twitter:scalding_2.9.2:0.8.1' 
    compile 'cascading:cascading-core:2.1.6'
    compile 'cascading:cascading-hadoop:2.1.6'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.7'
    testCompile 'org.scala-tools.testing:specs:1.6.2.2_1.5.0'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}

jar {
  description = "Assembles a Hadoop-ready JAR file"
  manifest {
    attributes( "Main-Class": "org.playground.readCsv" )
  }
}
```

This compiles and builds successfully but trying to run the jar throws this error:

```
$ java -jar build/libs/playground.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/playground/readCsv
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.playground.readCsv
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

My educated guess is that having the job extend from `Job` fails to conform some convention and doesn't look like a valid Main-Class, but I won't expect it to complain about not finding it.

Other possibility is that running it as `java -jar jarname` is incorrect and I just need run it with hadoop or something along those lines.

Anyway and just to validate: What is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source file is in the wrong location. By default, it needs to go into `src/main/scala/org/playground/readCsv.scala`. Otherwise, it won't even get compiled.

Comment: I sure missed that bit of setup.

Comment: mmm... Now it seems not to be picking the right path from the environment: https://dpaste.de/yThN

Comment: You need to pass the correct class path to the `java` command (`-cp ...`). At the very least, the class path will need to contain the Scala and Scalding Jar(s). Gradle's `application` plugin will take care of this for you. The `java` command doesn't know anything about `SCALA_LIBRARY_PATH`. (Perhaps the `scala` command does, but then you'll still need to provide the Scalding Jar, and possibly also other Jars.) If you want to create a self-contained executable Jar, look into the `gradle-one-jar` plugin.

Comment: This is intended to be Hadoop job. So it will end up being one fat jar.
Did I really miss that much of the manual or is this not that documented. I'll look into that gradle-one-jar thing, thank you.

Comment: You aren't creating a fat Jar. I already answered how to create a fat Jar in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018342/provided-dependency-failing-to-provide.

Comment: I explained how to do this in the question I linked to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50817/discussion-between-tutuca-and-peter-niederwieser)